# A/V Sync issues after update to 2.79

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

My video clips which are pulled From [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), do not line up on blender. I have A/V Sync on. the videos FPS on [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) say it is at 30 fps (plus the raw files DO sync when played back in [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)) and that is what I am trying to render at. Even though the channels do not line up when I render them they come out matching. Now when I try to make the channels line up when editing them and I try to render then the A/V is out of sync in the rendered video.

Comment: [Possibly Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length/61078#61078) are you using the VSE?

Comment: Yes I am, is that not recommended?

Comment: The input file is FLV and the Output I am aiming for is MPEG4

Comment: Are you sure this does not happen, with the same identical file, on 2.78 or another previous version? Your question title seems to say that...

Comment: Correct. I placed some raw files that I had turned into videos in the past with no issues and they do the same thing. I believe before the update i was using 2.78c.

Comment: I was not sure if a setting in my OBS was changed but everything is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is with OBS FLV files and Blender but I changed my OBS output to mp4 files and the issue is not there with that type. It may have something to do with the FLV files not specifying a Frame rate. When I check the properties > details of the files there is very little information. Blender may just be trying to compensate?

Answer (score 2):

I just edited an OBS file in Blender's VSE and Blender auto-conformed the project frame rate to FPS: 10 FramerateBase: 0.330. So its not quite 30fps. If you added something else to the project first then added the OBS file later, then Blender will default to the first specified frame rate. Either try this rate or add the OBS file first.

[image: Project Custom Frame Rate]

Consider checking that you are using SDL as your Audio Device in Blender preferences.

[image: prefs audio device]

Comment: Yes it changes this for me as well. Have you watched the video back after rendering? My video is about 8 minutes long and at the end the sync is off by about 10 seconds... more or less. I am only using one video file (and the audio that comes with it)

Comment: Like i said the video IS at 30 FPS. Maybe this is more of an audio issue instead of a video issue... I am not sure. when i put the rendered video back into blender the sync is good but like i said i put it in as 30 fps because it tries to automaticly move it to the custom 30.3 but the VSE says it is not synced.

Comment: Also this new version came from steam... i hope thats not the issue

Comment: Hmm, my video is 9 mins 40 secs and it looks rock solid. In fact its a video of a voice against a waveform recorded off a computer screen, so i have a good sync relationship. have you tried changing the Preferences>Audio Device>SDL?

Comment: Did you try rendering it out as mkv with h264 codec?

Comment: I just changed that as well as uninstalled the steam version and went directly to the website. Still nothing has changed.

Comment: As a last last suggestion, can you transode the clip using mpeg streamclip or ffmpeg just to see that the file isnt somehow corrupt?

Comment: Also try caching the clip via the strip properties panel?

Comment: Ok I changed the OBS file from FLV to an mp4 and it looks like it may work... I will get back with the result.

Comment: Yup that seems to have done it... not sure why the new version is having issues with FLV files from obs but... oh well.