# Video Not Importing Correctly, I think

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

When I add my video, it seems like it doesn't have the correct fps or total frames or something. Considering the clip is 29.97 fps and 1:41:08 long, I would think there should be more than 181866 total frames. When I import, I either end up with the video bar stopping well short of the audio bar where the back end of the video is missing, or they are both the same length but, again, back end of the video is missing. If I render out, I get a video where the audio plays at the correct speed, but the video is in slow motion and ends well short of the true end. How do I fix this?
[Video editing. Audio and Video strip have different length](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length) does not fix it.

Comment: It would help to know what format the video is in, including the container, video codec and audio codec, and what frame rate you have set for rendering, as well as what you mean by 'add my video clip', which I assume means to add it to the video sequence editor using the add movie command.

Comment: It sounds like a mismatched frame rate.

Comment: The video is in mpg or vob and is MPEG-2 and AC-3. I have 29.97 fps set for rendering as that is what Blender and the file's properties say it is (I suspect it may actually be 23.98 and is lying to me - how would I fix that?). "Add my video clip" means I add it to the sequencer editor.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length didn't fix the problem. I think the file is lying about it's fps. If I change it to what it should be, I get the same results: slow motion video with normal audio. The audio plays to the end but the video ends well before it should.